# Destructuring map function arguments in clojure: does the map need to go last?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I'm trying to define a function that takes a map and a regular argument, and I'd like to destructure parts of the map, something like

```
(defn do-stuff
  [[{:keys [foo bar]} where] what]
  (println foo bar what))
```

but when I call the function I get an error

```
; Execution error (UnsupportedOperationException) at .../do-stuff (REPL:34).
; nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
```

If I swap function arguments

```
(defn do-stuff
  [what [{:keys [foo bar]} where]]
  (println foo bar what))
```

everything works fine. Of course I could just write a `let` inside the function and do the destructuring there, but I wonder what I'm missing...

**EDIT**: to clarify I expect to be able to call the function like

```
(do-stuff {:foo "something" :bar "something else"} "baz")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you fail to show us, what your call there is, my guess is, that
you are confusing the `let` syntax for destructuring with the one on
functions.

So the following calls work - note the nesting in a vector of the map
and the dangling `where`:

```clj
(defn do-stuff
  [[{:keys [foo bar]} where] what]
  (println foo bar what))

(do-stuff [{:foo 1 :bar 2} 3] 4)
; 1 2 4

(defn do-stuff
  [what [{:keys [foo bar]} where]]
  (println foo bar what))

(do-stuff 0 [{:foo 1 :bar 2} 3])
; 1 2 0
```

Although you don't print `where`, it seems like you want to hold on to
the map itself.  But this is done via `:as`.

```clj
(defn do-stuff
  [{:keys [foo bar] :as where} what]
  (println foo bar where what))

(do-stuff {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3} 4)
; 1 2 {:foo 1, :bar 2, :baz 3} 4
```

#### edit

The reason, why things happening as they are happening falls back to
this:

Positional destructuring works for strings (it gives the character on
the position, but then the map-destructuring fails, because a char is no
map.  But it fails gracefully and just assigns `nil` to the two key
variables.

But when a map is provided instead it fails hard, because they can not
destructured positionally (accessed via `nth`), hence the error message.

```clj
(defn do-stuff
  [[{:keys [foo bar]}]]
  (println foo bar))

(do-stuff "baz")
; nil nil
(do-stuff {:foo "something" :bar "something else"})
; throws
```